# Installing Xfce on CentOS 7 via ansible yum

Tags: ssh, ansible, centos7, yum

I have a Centos 7 machine freshly started from the `centos/7` vagrant base box. I provision the box via ansible but the following does not work:

```
- name: Install xfce
  yum:
    name: "@^Xfce"
    state: present
    enablerepo: "epel"
```

The error is:

> TASK [desktop : Install xfce]
>   ************************************************** fatal: [xxx]: FAILED! => {"changed": false,
>   "changes": {"installed": ["@^Xfce"]}, "msg": "Error: Nothing to do\n",
>   "rc": 1, "results": ["Loaded plugins: fastestmirror\nLoading mirror
>   speeds from cached hostfile\n * base: mirror.ratiokontakt.de\n * epel:
>   mirror.de.leaseweb.net\n * extras: centos.schlundtech.de\n * updates:
>   centos.schlundtech.de\nGroup Xfce does not exist.\n"]}

Yet, running the following command from within the machine works:

`sudo yum --enablerepo=epel -y groups install "Xfce"`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [yum module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_module.html):

> Yum itself has two types of groups. “Package groups” are specified in the rpm itself while “environment groups” are specified in a separate file (usually by the distribution). Unfortunately, this division becomes apparent to ansible users because ansible needs to operate on the group of packages in a single transaction and yum requires groups to be specified in different ways when used in that way. Package groups are specified as “@development-tools” and environment groups are “@^gnome-desktop-environment”. Use the “yum group list hidden ids” command to see which category of group the group you want to install falls into.

You're specifying your grouop as `@^Xfce`, which is the syntax for an "environment group", but if you look at the output of `yum group list hidden ids` there is no "Xfce" environment group.  There *is* a package group by that name, and this playbook seems to install it successfully:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: install xfce
      yum:
        name: "@Xfce"
        state: "present"
        enablerepo: "epel"
```